# Dependencies between plugins

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, plugins

I wrote an app which uses plugins, everything is ok, I made my plugins with the bundle template of Xcode.

Now, I need to write a plugin that depends on another plugin, let's say plugin A depends on plugin B.

I tried to link plugin A with plugin B by adding it to the project (link binary with libraries) but that does not work (tried with the full bundle and with the plugin object file inside the bundle).

The only way I found for the moment is to add source files of plugin B to the plugin A but it is bad because in the application, both plugin A and B contains same code (Class X is implemented in both Y and Z. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined).

How can I implement that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to achieve that.

Just copy or reference the header of the classes I need and then use the -U linker flag (in the Other Linker Flags option) in the following form :

-Wl,-U -Wl,_OBJC_CLASS_$_NameOfTheClass

(Wl option is needed, see here why : http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/264371-ld-undefined-symbols-argument-is-ignored.html )

The -U flag for a class allows to compile without having the definition of the class.

With that, I can compile the plugin without duplicating the code of plugin on which I depend.